# Mongoose populate nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Assuming the following 3 models:

```
var CarSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  partIds: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Part'}],
});

var PartSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  otherIds: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Other'}],
});

var OtherSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String}
});
```

When I query for Cars I can populate the parts:

```
Car.find().populate('partIds').exec(function(err, cars) {
  // list of cars with partIds populated
});
```

Is there a way in mongoose to populate the otherIds in the nested parts objects for all the cars.

```
Car.find().populate('partIds').exec(function(err, cars) {
  // list of cars with partIds populated
  // Try an populate nested
  Part.populate(cars, {path: 'partIds.otherIds'}, function(err, cars) {
    // This does not populate all the otherIds within each part for each car
  });
});
```

I can probably iterate over each car and try to populate:

```
Car.find().populate('partIds').exec(function(err, cars) {
  // list of cars with partIds populated

  // Iterate all cars
  cars.forEach(function(car) {
     Part.populate(car, {path: 'partIds.otherIds'}, function(err, cars) {
       // This does not populate all the otherIds within each part for each car
     });
  });
});
```

Problem there is that I have to use a lib like async to make the populate call for each and wait until all are done and then return.

Possible to do without looping over all cars?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Update:** Please see [Trinh Hoang Nhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444739/1765851) for a more compact version that was added in Mongoose 4. Summarized below:

```
Car
  .find()
  .populate({
    path: 'partIds',
    model: 'Part',
    populate: {
      path: 'otherIds',
      model: 'Other'
    }
  })
```

---

**Mongoose 3 and below:**

```
Car
  .find()
  .populate('partIds')
  .exec(function(err, docs) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    Car.populate(docs, {
      path: 'partIds.otherIds',
      model: 'Other'
    },
    function(err, cars) {
      if(err) return callback(err);
      console.log(cars); // This object should now be populated accordingly.
    });
  });
```

For nested populations like this, you have to tell mongoose the Schema you want to populate from.

Comment: Crap RTFM ;)  I see that now.  However no matter what I try I get back an empty array for otherIds.  As a sanity check If I don't call the populate method there is an array of id's (which is correct).  Populate is not populating those ids.  Running 3.8.22 lastest from npm

Comment: Also have logging turned on.  I do not see another call to the other collection to populate the 'join'.  So mongoose isn't even making the call.

Comment: @lostintranslation It should be `model: 'Other'` in that nested `populate` call.

Comment: @JohnnyHK to the rescue again, thanks! As a side note I though I might be able to get it all the first call Car.find().populate('partIds').populate({path: 'partIds.otherIds', model: 'Other').exec ...  No luck guess you have to make the first query call to populate the partIds first.

Comment: Or, you can try the [mongoose-deep-populate plugin](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) and rewrite the entire thing with: `Car.find().deepPopulate('partIds.otherIds').exec(...)`.  (Disclaimer: I'm the author.)

Comment: The first example worked awesomely for me. Does the model property take anything other than a string, or can you pass an schema reference?

Answer (score 29):

Mongoose 4 support this

```
Car
.find()
.populate({
  path: 'partIds',
  model: 'Part',
  populate: {
    path: 'otherIds',
    model: 'Other'
  }
})
```

Comment: Note: model: 'Other' is necessary. Without it, it gives empty array. Docs doesn't specify it : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate

Comment: But I want to do double populate in one nested level. So basically something like below, 

Car
.find()
.populate({
  path: 'partIds',
  model: 'Part',
  populate: {
    path: 'otherIds',
    model: 'Other'
  }
  populate: {
    path: 'ModelIds',
    model: 'Model'
  }
})

Answer (score 4):

Use [mongoose deepPopulate plugin](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate)

```
car.find().deepPopulate('partIds.otherIds').exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's should be better with

```
Car
.find()
.populate({
    path: 'partIds.othersId'
})
```