# Mongoose / Mongodb - should I explicitly add objectid to populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have 2 models, one is `users` and the other is `sessions`.

It was initially setup as:

```
const users = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: {type: String, unique: true},
}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', users,);
```

I then went on and added another model, called sessions,

```
const sessions = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, null: false},
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    timestamp: {type: Date},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Sessions', sessions);
```

I then decided, I want to to be able to pull the user's sessions along with the users and added 
    `sessions: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SurfSessions', default: null}]` to my users model schema.

I quickly learnt that `users.findOne(username:admin).populate('sessions')` isn't gonna fill up sessions by itself, as `sessions` returns as an empty array `[]`.

Since I don't have `sessions` inside `users` populated with `objectid`'s does that mean I cannot populate `sessions` or is there another way?

Comment: Please checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179720/mongoose-populate-nested-array) post which has the similar question

Comment: Thanks, been through that question many times before, but still doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with virtual populate:

```
const users = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
  },
  { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', users);
```

Then:

```
userSchema.virtual('sessions', {
  ref: 'Session', // model to search in
  foreignField: 'user_id', 
  localField: '_id', // checks where user_id on session === _id on user
});
```

After this, use .populate('sessions') as normal. For more check this out: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#populate