# Querying nested Schema in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

i'm learning MongoDB for a few weeks now and i have still no idea how to query nested documents in my project. I read the MongoDB-docs and googled a lot, but i found no good explanations or tutorials for my problem. Maybe you can help me!

I have three Collections which are referencing each other:

```
const shipmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  cityId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "City",
  },
});

const citiesShcema = new mongoose.Schema({
  cityName: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
  },
  countryId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Countries",
    required: true,
  },
});

const countriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  countryName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Shipment_new = mongoose.model("Shipment_new", shipmentSchema);
const Cities = mongoose.model("City", citiesShcema);
const Country = mongoose.model("Countries", countriesSchema);
```

So, guys I was wondering if there's way to query shipments from a country... **I mean I want to get all shipments with in a country**. So, I tried to work it solved with my own and this what I tried:

```
const filterShipment = {
  cityId: {
    countryId: "5f6bbe558b094c14103a7776",
  },
};

const shimpents = await Shipment_new.find(filterShipment);
```

But this didn't do the work so guys, you may wanna help me out here.... I just want get the shipments of a specific countray? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: try nested populate query :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179720/mongoose-populate-nested-array/28180427

Comment: Can you please add sample JSON input for the collection? I will try it in MongoDB query.

Answer (score 0):

For querying multiple documents in mongo (Joins in SQL) you need to use `$lookup`. Based on what i uderstood from question, Below query gives you all the `shipments` by `countryId`.

Here is the query. I have also added mongo playground. So that you can run the query. And make some changes if needed.

```js
db.Shipment_new.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "City",
      "localField": "cityId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "city"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$city"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "city.countryId": 111
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      item: 1,
      city: "$city.cityName",
      countryId: "$city.countryId"
    }
  }
])
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZfeOgLKSrCE)